# Rails 3.2 - Formtastic gem won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 application and I'm planning to install activeadmin for managing resources. However, when I add `gem 'activeadmin'` to the Gemfile and run `bundle`, it produces this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occured while installing formtastic (2.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install formtastic -v '2.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Sure enough, when I try to install formtastic only, and add `gem formtastic` to the Gemfile and run `bundle`, I get the same error. Is anybody else experiencing this? I've tried formtastic versions 2.2.1 and 2.1.1 by the way (because active admin require ~> 2.1.1). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you out http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/04/installing-rails-gem-fails-with-undefined-method-spec-for-nilnilclass-error/

Comment: Cool, the same thing happened to me, but in my case, Ubuntu froze. Thanks, I just learned what to do in case of a blackout while installing gems. :)